# How to Display an Enum entity Name in Angular/TypeScript?

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to Display the Name of my Enum Entity within an AngularApp.

This is my Enum:

```
export enum Type{
  All = 'All',
  TOOL_H = 'Some..',
  TOOL_B = 'Stuff.."',
  TOOL_S = 'to..',
  TOOL_C = 'Show..',
}
```

in my *app.component.ts* i've added an method which returns an object of the Enum:

```
public get Type() {
  return Type; 
}
```

Now i'm trying to Display the Name of the Entry "Tool_H". But is there a way the get the String "Some..."?

I've also tried it with this statement, but nothing appears on the Page

```
<div *ngIf="tool.type === Type.TOOL_H">Some...</div>
```

If i'm just use the {{ tool.type }} it displays "Tool_H"

Comment: Where is `tool` defined? If you reference `Type.TOOL_H` it will be "Some...". Try a `console.log(Type.TOOL_H)`.

Comment: A Few lines above this statement i have an **ngFor="let tool of tools; let i = index"*

And yes, if i refer Type.TOOL_H the Console logs "Some..."

Comment: I think that's the answer :) you _can_ refer to the value of the enum directly just like you did in the console.log. If nothing shows on your page, it *must* be because `tool.type` is not equal to "Some...".

Comment: erm... tool.type is actual "Tool_H"

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood the question. If `tool.type` is "Tool_H", the condition basically says `if ("Tool_H" === "Some...") {`, which is obviously false. Am I correct in guessing you want to reference the key of the enum in the condition rather than the value?

Comment: Damn my mind is completely messed up right now xD

My Object `tool.type` saves the Key `Tool_H`
With his information that i get, i want to resolve the Value and Show it on the Page

Sorry if i confuse you. The combination of a German who tries it's first time Angular/TS might be not the best ^^

Answer (score 0):

if you use something like this `Type['TOOL_H']` in html you get `'Some..'`,
so it's useful for showing your enum.

```
<span>{{Type['TOOL_H']}}</span> // resault: 'Some..'
```

Answer (score 0):

(First, a piece of advice: I wouldn't use a name like 'Type' for my 'code-stuff-naming', so similar to some possible Angular reserved word).

I guess you are giving the same name to your enum (Type) and to your 'Type' variable (with the getter 'get Type()').

Try something simpler as:

```
export enum Type{
  All = 'All',
  TOOL_H = 'Some..',
  TOOL_B = 'Stuff..',
  TOOL_S = 'to..',
  TOOL_C = 'Show..',
}


// NOTE: If you don't have the enum definition in 'app.component.ts', import it with something like:
// import {Type} from '../../commons/enums/...';

// Forget the getter:
//public get Type() {
// return Type; 
// }

public showByType(toolType: string, myTypeSelected: string) {
   return toolType === myType
}

<div *ngIf="showByType(tool.type, Type.TOOL_B)">Some...</div>
```

Something like this should work well (I'm sorry, I didn't test it).

For the rest of the cases, you just have to change the enum:

```
<div *ngIf="showByType(tool.type, Type.TOOL_B)">'Stuff.."</div>
...
```